# Can the Google Search appliance generate a report showing broken links on your site?

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics

I know the Google Search Appliance has access to this information (as this factors into the PageRank Algorithm), but is there a way to export this information from the crawler appliance?

External tools won't work because a significant portion of the content is for a corporate intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free tool called Xenu turned out the be the weapon of choice for this task.  http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#Download

Answer (score 3):

Might be something available on Google, but I have never checked.  I usually use the [link checker provided by W3C](http://validator.w3.org/checklink).  The W3C one can also detect redirects which is useful if your server handles 404s by redirecting instead of returning a 404 status code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to view, among other things, broken links on your site.

This won't show you broken links to external sites though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not possible. Under Status and Reports > Crawl Diagnostics there are
2 styles of report available: the directory drill-down 'Tree View'
and the 100 URLs at a time 'List View'. Some people have tried creating programs to page through the List View
but this seems to fail after a few thousand URLs.

My advice is to use your server logs instead.
Make sure that 404 and referrer URL logging are enabled on your web server,
since you will probably want to correct the page containing the broken link.

You could then use a [log file analyser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_log_analysis_software) to generate a broken link report.

To create an effective, long-term way of monitoring your broken links, you may want to set up a cron job to do the following:

- Use `grep` to extract lines containing 404 entries from the server log file.
- Use `sed` to remove everything except requested URLs and referrer URLs from every line.
- Use `sort` and `uniq` commands to remove duplicates from the list.
- Output the result to a new file each time so that you can monitor changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just analyze your webserver logs and look for all the 404 pages?  That makes far more sense and is much more reliable.

Comment: We're moving around 700,000 pages to a new CMS system and the server logs only catch the ones people are actively clicking on.

Comment: The logs will also show 404s from clients such as the GSA crawler. If the GSA has detected a given URL then so has the server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but you can use the Export URLs feature on the GSA admin console then look for URLs with a state of not_found. This will show you all the URLs that the GSA has discovered but returned it a 404 when it attempted to crawl them.